# PHP adding +1 more to each item

Tags: php

I'm trying to add an integer to each item in a PHP loop. So the first item gets +1, the second item gets +2, third item +3.... etc.

I found the code to add the same number to each item, but I want it to increase per item.

Here is what I'm using now to get +.1 to each item.

```
$delay = 0.1;
foreach ($posts as $post){
    $delay+= .1;
}
```

What would I do to add +.1 more to each item?

Comment: does $delay = $delay + 0.1; work?

Comment: This is not an integer these are floats, you would basically need a count which does it x * 0.1 so it ends up as you wish, to add the value you would do: `$delay+=(count*0.1);

Comment: Why loop? `$delay = count($posts) * 0.1`?

Comment: I misunderstood your question therefor mark b has the best answer so far

Comment: I think he wants for each item to add a delay and do something with it, not to get the complete delay.

Comment: Ah, that opened up a new idea to utilize the post count and then multiply by my number to get a different number for each that I use as a load delay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a 0-based integer indexed array with sequential keys, you could do something like this:

```
$delayBase = $delay = 0.1;
foreach ($posts as $k => $post){
        $delay += ($k + 1)($delayBase);
}
```

On the first iteration (when `$k` is 0), it will add 0.1 to `$delay`.  The second iteration will add (2 * 0.1) or 0.2 to `$delay`.  The third iteration will add (3 * 0.1) or 0.3 and so on.

**Update**

I think @MarcB is correct in the comments, you don't even need to loop to calculate the sum of the first *n* elements in an arithmetic series (here the series being 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ...)  The general form of the equation (found [here](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/sum-of-the-first-n-terms-of-an-arithmetic-series.html)) is:

> S<sub>n</sub> = n(a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>n</sub>) / 2

Where *n* is the number of terms we're looking to sum in the series, a<sub>1</sub> is the first term, and a<sub>n</sub> is the last term in the series.

Following this, we can reduce the code to this:

```
$numPosts = count($posts);
$sum = ($numPosts(0.1 + ($numPosts * 0.1)) / 2)
$delay = 0.1 + $sum;
```

This will also get around a potential issue if `$posts` happens to be an associative array, not start at 0 or have gaps or holes in the indices.

Comment: You could easily just add to the value, but i like this. Vote up.

Comment: What if first key is `10` or `a`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver then OP will need a different solution, hence my caveats at the beginning.

Comment: This is great! You made it make sense to me. Utilizing the `$numPosts` and multiplying by my delay number made it do exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$delay = 0.1;
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($posts); $i++){
    $posts[i] += $i*delay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$delay = $i = 0.1; 
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $delay+= $i; 
    $i += 0.1;
}
```